# Replace an element in a sorted set in scala

Tags: scala, set, sorting

How do I replace the first element in a sorted set in Scala? Is there an analogous function to 'patch' for Sorted Sets? Is it even possible?

```
val a = SortedSet(1,5,6)
val b = a.patch(0, seq[2], 1)
println(b)
```

Result should be:

```
TreeSet(2, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Sets do not have the notion of 'index', so strictly speaking `patch` would make no sense here. You can create a function that takes a tuple (`ElemToReplace -> ReplaceWith`), then remove the element you want to replace and add a new one. By the way, what would happen in your example if you wanted to remove `1` and replace it with `5`? :) The result set should still be `(5,6)`...

Comment: Sorted sets have ordered elements, which is the same thing as index. So for me, patch does make sense. But I would also like to know the desired result if the new value already exists in the set or ends up in a different place in the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> val a = SortedSet(1,5,6)
a: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 5, 6)


scala> val b = a.drop(1) + 2
b: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(2, 5, 6)
```

Note: You're not really replacing anything here (at least not like an array.) What you are doing is taking a `SortedSet` and using `drop` to remove the first element (which happens to be the lowest value in sorted order in this case) and then you are adding another element to the set. `2` is only in the first position because that is where it is supposed to be in sorted order.

```
scala> a.drop(1) + 10
res21: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(5, 6, 10)
```

As you see, if you add `10`, it also takes its place in sorted order which is at the end.

Furthermore, because sets cannot contain duplicates, doing something like:

```
scala> a.drop(1) + 6
res22: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(5, 6)
```

removes the first element and leaves you with only two elements in the set. This is because `6` was already in the set, so it is not added (again, a property of a set is that it does not contain duplicates.)